# Visual Studio for Mac search with regular expression

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Is it possible to search with regular expression in *Visual Studio for Mac*?

I want to search like below in **Search In Solution...**

> /x:Name="*"/g

I tried to search with `x:Name` keyword, but Search Result only search `x`...

### Search

[image: Search]

### Search Result

[image: Search Result]

Comment: If you use the Find in Files dialog (Search - Find in Files) you can select to use a 'Regex search'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio for Mac, press Shift-Command-F or go to Search -> Find in Files... to open the dialog.

Make sure there is a checkmark next to "Regex search" as in the following screenshot of the dialog.

[image]